# How can I resume a download with wget?

Tags: command-line, firefox, downloads, wget

I use wget with Flashgot in Firefox to download. I can't resume download if i pause(by ctrl+c). Because, i don't know the commandline arguments of wget to manually add it in a terminal.
So i did following steps to get those commandline arguments, when wget started downloading. After these procedures, i pressed ctrl+c to pause download:

1. `ps -A | grep -i wget` and copied the pid of wget suppose it is 16760
2. `xargs -0 echo < /proc/16760/cmdline > ls.txt` (From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821837/how-to-get-the-command-line-args-passed-to-a-running-process-on-unix-linux-syste)

Now,  ls.txt contains:

```
wget --trust-server-names -c -O PSY_GENTLEMAN_M_V_hd720.mp4 --directory-prefix=/home/aliyans/Downloads --referer=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ASO_zypdnsQ --user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0 http://r5---sn-gxap5ojx-h55e.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?ipbits=8&sparams=cp%2Cgcr%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Cratebypass%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&gcr=in&source=youtube&ip=115.242.140.33&mv=m&ms=au&fexp=906370%2C913574%2C913811%2C932000%2C932004%2C906383%2C916911%2C916910%2C902000%2C901208%2C919512%2C929903%2C925714%2C929119%2C931202%2C900821%2C900823%2C909419%2C911416%2C908529%2C930807%2C919373%2C930803%2C906836%2C920201%2C929602%2C930101%2C930609%2C926403%2C900824%2C912711&ratebypass=yes&mt=1366553656&sver=3&itag=22&id=0123bfcf2a5d9ec4&newshard=yes&expire=1366577026&upn=ByXHIHSd5Uc&key=yt1&cp=U0hVS1VSVV9HUENONV9NTFlBOkRWZzI0MEJKeDBt&signature=BD13D36DD291572B599B536476EC1247E7C487C9.34F8B3C3F0BF8198C68C4490EC4257650A569DC6
```

I copied the above line and pasted in a terminal. But it showed:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

How can i resume a download from wget which was started by FlashGot? or Is there any other method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put quotes around the `--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0` part to prevent the shell from interpreting the parenthesis and semicolon, or just omit that argument entirely as it shouldn't be needed.

Comment: I did as you suggested(Completely omitted that argument). But some other issue showed up:    `Connecting to r5---sn-gxap5ojx-h55e.c.youtube.com (r5---sn-gxap5ojx-h55e.c.youtube.com)|115.254.121.208|:80... connected. HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden 2013-04-23 09:09:28 ERROR 403: Forbidden.`

Comment: @001neeraj, and when you don't omit the argument?

Comment: When i use the output from `xargs -0 echo < /proc/16760/cmdline > ls.txt` it shows the above error

Comment: @001neeraj, did you not read the first part of my answer?

Comment: when i include user-agent argument, it shows    `bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('`    And when i exclude the argument, it shows    `Connecting to r5---sn-gxap5ojx-h55e.c.youtube.com (r5---sn-gxap5ojx-h55e.c.youtube.com)|115.254.121.208|:80... connected. HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden 2013-04-23 09:09:28 ERROR 403: Forbidden.`

Comment: @001neeraj, you are ignoring the first words in my answer.  "You need to put quotes around..."